Aviation headset microphone amplifier circuit
I realize that this is an old thread, but I just stumbled upon it. I built the circuit that Andy posted here and it works great.  The only changes I made were using a 2N5089 transistor, EM-9745un microphone and a 220 μF, 16 V electrolytic capacitor only because I had these lying around from another project.
I'm new to circuits and components and have a few questions and I'm eager to learn.
I assume by 100 μ listed in the schematic, you meant 100 μF electrolytic capacitor?  Would there be any difference in using the 100 μF vs a 220 μF caacitor?  Is there a physically smaller 100 μF capacitor that could be used, or possibly a ceramic capacitor as I have limited space in my current project box?
What difference would there be in the listed transistor and the one I used?
Lastly, what could I change to adjust the gain on the microphone as it's a little loud?
Andy aka's circuit:


Microphone datasheet is here. Also look over this page's figure 4 as well as other pages there.

Will do, thanks.

The electrolytic cap is just to provide a clean DC bias source for the mic, and it's value is not critical. Do not use a much smaller value that 100µF, because low frequencies would be lost due to negative feedback. BTW, "u" mayb be used for "µ" on occasion (though mu is easy to type as Alt + Numeric Keypad 0181, if you don't have ελληνική γλώσσα keyboard).
As for the transistors, look up the spec sheets online, but if it ain't broke, don't fix it.
For a simple volume control, try a 50kΩ variable resistor in series with T1's base lead. Again, the value is not critical -- a larger variable resistor would just use a smaller portion of its range. Caveat: this might introduce a very small amount of noise.

@MrGerber It's not a feature of the keyboard itself but the OS and OS keyboard settings how it wants to interpret something when you push AltGr+M or anything else on the keyboard.

Great, thanks very much for the info fellas.  I'll give it a shot and report back.

I tried the 50kΩ variable resistor on T1's base lead and didn't notice any change when adjusting it.  I did try 500Ω variable resistor in place of the 100R and noticed I could vary the gain that way.  Not sure if this is the correct way to do this.

From the datasheet on your electret microphone, the model you use for simulation should look like this:

The SENS and RL and IMAX are taken directly from the datasheet for the microphone capsule you mentioned.
The older RTCA DO-170 standard has been replaced by DO-214A. The older standard covers \$12\:\text{V}\$ and \$24\:\text{V}\$ systems. Either way, the test circuit is something like this:

I don't know which system you have. But amplified microphone systems should probably be designed to work with either.
I haven't seen the updated details in DO-214A. So I can't comment on that.
The load should appear to be about \$600\:\Omega\$ in total. That includes the test circuit's source resistance of \$470\:\Omega\$.
Your circuit, combined with the transceiver system, looks about like this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
\$R_1\$ and \$C_1\$ form a very simple RC low-pass filter while also supplying quiescent DC current needed by the circuit and the electret. The goal would be to completely eliminate the output signal but in this case the output signal will be only down by a factor of about 100 at \$34\:\text{Hz}\$. So that may be the reason for the large value. You could try and reduce it. But the results may not be acceptable. So it's up to you how to handle it. A more complex circuit might be used to reduce the size. But this existing method is easier.
Your electret requires about \$1\:\text{V}\$ to operate (not \$2\:\text{V}\$.) Since the supply rail can be as little as about \$8\:\text{V}\$ this means that the sum of \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ cannot exceed \$\frac{8\:\text{V}-1\:\text{V}}{500\:\mu\text{A}}=14\:\text{k}\Omega\$.
If you reduce \$R_1\$ then the RC filter doesn't work as well, but it allows \$R_2\$ to be larger, which increases the voltage gain. Luckily, you don't want higher gain. So this suggests some trade-offs. You could reduce the magnitude of \$C_1\$ while increasing the magnitude of \$R_1\$ without changing the roll-off of the RC filter. Then lower the magnitude of \$R_2\$, reducing the overall voltage gain in the process.
For example, perhaps try raising \$R_1\$ to \$10\:\text{k}\Omega\$, reducing \$C_1\$ to \$47\:\mu\text{F}\$ and reducing \$R_2\$ to anywhere between \$2.7\:\text{k}\Omega\$ and \$3.9\:\text{k}\Omega\$. There still should be enough current for the electret, I think. But this should be able to reduce your gain.
(A potentiometer could also be considered in combination with \$R_1\$ and \$R_2\$ but you've said space is limited. So that's out.)
If you have a \$24\:\text{V}\$ system then \$R_1\$ plus \$R_2\$ cannot exceed about \$30\:\text{k}\Omega\$ and you could certainly further reduce the magnitude of \$C_1\$.
Are you on a \$12\:\text{V}\$ system or a \$24\:\text{V}\$ system?

Awesome info, thanks.  A lot of it went over my head as I'm no electrical engineer.  I will test out your suggestions and report back.  I actually could get a small variable resistor in my project box and just drill a hole in the top if I need to.  I'll test this all out on my breadboard first.
Our aircraft is a 12v system with a Garmin GMA340 audio panel.  Aircraft headsets are universal and work in any aircraft.  I'm fairly certain the voltage is stepped down in the audio panel no matter what volt system the aircraft is.

@JetLink I may be building an RV-10, starting next year. Still checking out a place to do the work in Bend, OR. But from the standard I pointed to, a 24 V system supplies about 16 V instead of 8 V, as I gather it. The new standard specifically says "not carbon". So I'm gathering that carbon mics are very much on the decline, now.
